# how to create multi tar archives for a huge folder

Tags: linux, filesystems, tar, large-files

I have a large folder with 30M small files. I hope to backup the folder into 30 archives, each tar.gz file will have 1M files. The reason to split into multi archives is that to untar one single large archive will take month.. pipe tar to split also won't work because when untar the file, I have to cat all archives together.

Also, I hope not to mv each file to a new dir, because even ls is very painful for this huge folder.

Comment: If your question is how to split your list of 30000 files into 30 lists of 1000 files each, `xargs -L` may be helpful.

Comment: `tar` isn't `zip`. Please don't confuse them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote this bash script to do it.
It basically forms an array containing the names of the files to go into each tar, then starts `tar` in **parallel on all of them**.
It might not be the most efficient way, but it will get the job done as you want.
I can expect it to consume large amounts of memory though.

You will need to adjust the options in the start of the script.
You might also want to change the tar options `cvjf` in the last line (like removing the verbose output `v` for performance or changing compression `j` to `z`, etc ...).

## Script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# User configuratoin
#===================
files=(*.log)           # Set the file pattern to be used, e.g. (*.txt) or (*)
num_files_per_tar=5 # Number of files per tar
num_procs=4         # Number of tar processes to start
tar_file_dir='/tmp' # Tar files dir
tar_file_name_prefix='tar' # prefix for tar file names
tar_file_name="$tar_file_dir/$tar_file_name_prefix"

# Main algorithm
#===============
num_tars=$((${#files[@]}/num_files_per_tar))  # the number of tar files to create
tar_files=()  # will hold the names of files for each tar

tar_start=0 # gets update where each tar starts
# Loop over the files adding their names to be tared
for i in `seq 0 $((num_tars-1))`
do
  tar_files[$i]="$tar_file_name$i.tar.bz2 ${files[@]:tar_start:num_files_per_tar}"
  tar_start=$((tar_start+num_files_per_tar))
done

# Start tar in parallel for each of the strings we just constructed
printf '%s\n' "${tar_files[@]}" | xargs -n$((num_files_per_tar+1)) -P$num_procs tar cjvf
```

## Explanation

First, all the file names that match the selected pattern are stored in the array `files`. Next, the for loop slices this array and forms strings from the slices. The number of the slices is equal to the number of the desired tarballs. The resulting strings are stored in the array `tar_files`. The for loop also adds the name of the resulting tarball to the beginning of each string. The elements of `tar_files` take the following form (assuming 5 files/tarball):

```bsh
tar_files[0]="tar0.tar.bz2  file1 file2 file3 file4 file5"
tar_files[1]="tar1.tar.bz2  file6 file7 file8 file9 file10"
...
```

The last line of the script, `xargs` is used to start multiple `tar` processes (up to the maximum specified number) where each one will process one element of `tar_files` array in parallel.

## Test

List of files:

```bsh
$ls

a      c      e      g      i      k      m      n      p      r      t
b      d      f      h      j      l      o      q      s
```

Generated Tarballs:
    $ls /tmp/tar*
    tar0.tar.bz2  tar1.tar.bz2  tar2.tar.bz2  tar3.tar.bz2

Answer (score 4):

Here's another script. You can choose whether you want precisely one million files per segment, or precisely 30 segments. I've gone with the former in this script, but the `split` keyword allows either choice.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
DIR="$1"        # The source of the millions of files
TARDEST="$2"    # Where the tarballs should be placed

# Create the million-file segments
rm -f /tmp/chunk.*
find "$DIR" -type f | split -l 1000000 - /tmp/chunk.

# Create corresponding tarballs
for CHUNK in $(cd /tmp && echo chunk.*)
do
    test -f "$CHUNK" || continue

    echo "Creating tarball for chunk '$CHUNK'" >&2
    tar cTf "/tmp/$CHUNK" "$TARDEST/$CHUNK.tar"
    rm -f "/tmp/$CHUNK"
done
```

There are a number of niceties that could be applied to this script. The use of `/tmp/chunk.` as the file list prefix should probably be pushed out into a constant declaration, and the code shouldn't really assume it can delete anything matching `/tmp/chunk.*`, but I've left it this way as a proof of concept rather than a polished utility. If I were using this I would use `mktemp` to create a temporary directory for holding the file lists.

Comment: I like the `split` idea: a neat solution to the large memory consumption I expect for my script ...

Comment: @Bichoy. Thank you. But you could reduce your memory consumption by serialising your `tar` commands :-)

Comment: I am assuming the main flow in my script is I have to main ALL the filenames in memory and create individual arrays out of that. Parallel execution of tar will be very beneficial here, since the files are small, it will probably be I/O limited and it is good to have multiple tar processes hanging around waiting for I/O operations to finish .. Just my opinion, what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

This one does precisely what was requested:

```
#!/bin/bash
ctr=0;
# Read 1M lines, strip newline chars, put the results into an array named "asdf"
while readarray -n 1000000 -t asdf; do
  ctr=$((${ctr}+1));
# "${asdf[@]}" expands each entry in the array such that any special characters in
# the filename won't cause problems
  tar czf /destination/path/asdf.${ctr}.tgz "${asdf[@]}";
# If you don't want compression, use this instead:
  #tar cf /destination/path/asdf.${ctr}.tar "${asdf[@]}";
# this is the canonical way to generate output
# for consumption by read/readarray in bash
done <(find /source/path -not -type d);
```

`readarray` (in bash) can also be used to execute a callback function, so that could potentially be re-written to resemble:

```
function something() {...}
find /source/path -not -type d \
  | readarray -n 1000000 -t -C something asdf
```

GNU `parallel` could be leveraged to do something similar (untested; I don't have `parallel` installed where I'm at so I'm winging it):

```
find /source/path -not -type d -print0 \
  | parallel -j4 -d '\0' -N1000000 tar czf '/destination/path/thing_backup.{#}.tgz'
```

Since that's untested you could add the `--dry-run` arg to see what it'll actually do.  I like this one the best, but not everyone has `parallel` installed.  `-j4` makes it use 4 jobs at a time, `-d '\0'` combined with `find`'s `-print0` makes it ignore special characters in the filename (whitespace, etc).  The rest should be self explanatory.

Something similar could be done with `parallel` but I don't like it because it generates random filenames:

```
find /source/path -not -type d -print0 \
  | parallel -j4 -d '\0' -N1000000 --tmpdir /destination/path --files tar cz
```

I don't [yet?] know of a way to make it generate sequential filenames.

`xargs` could also be used, but unlike `parallel` there's no straightforward way to generate the output filename so you'd end up doing something stupid/hacky like this:

```
find /source/path -not -type d -print0 \
  | xargs -P 4 -0 -L 1000000 bash -euc 'tar czf $(mktemp --suffix=".tgz" /destination/path/backup_XXX) "$@"'
```

The OP said they didn't want to use split ... I thought that seemed weird as `cat` will re-join them just fine; this produces a tar and splits it into 3gb chunks:

```
tar c /source/path | split -b $((3*1024*1024*1024)) - /destination/path/thing.tar.
```

... and this un-tars them into the current directory:

```
cat $(\ls -1 /destination/path/thing.tar.* | sort) | tar x
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another script: https://gist.github.com/s5unty/e636a1ca698c6817330825eba67941e7

1: pack /boot into multiple tar file

```
$ tar -c -v --index-file=pack.index -M -L 10M -f /dev/null -F pack.sh /boot && pack.sh END
————
-rw-r--r-- 1 8.8K Sep  1 22:30 pack~1.index     <-- file list
-rw-r--r-- 1  11M Sep  1 22:30 pack~1.tar       <-- tar file (not a multiple-part, is a whole/pure tar)
-rw-r--r-- 1  116 Sep  1 22:30 pack~2.index                                                             
-rw-r--r-- 1  11M Sep  1 22:30 pack~2.tar                                                               
-rw-r--r-- 1  107 Sep  1 22:30 pack~3.index                                                             
-rw-r--r-- 1  13M Sep  1 22:30 pack~3.tar                                                               
-rw-r--r-- 1  102 Sep  1 22:30 pack~4.index                                                             
-rw-r--r-- 1  15M Sep  1 22:30 pack~4.tar       <-- big tar file,
-rw-r--r-- 1 5.3M Sep  1 22:30 pack~4.tar.part2 <-- with second part
-rw-r--r-- 1    0 Sep  1 22:30 pack~5.index                                                             
-rw-r--r-- 1  10K Sep  1 22:30 pack~5.tar                                                               
-rw-r--r-- 1    0 Sep  1 22:30 pack~x.index     <-- the last (~x)
-rw-r--r-- 1  10K Sep  1 22:30 pack~x.tar       <-- the last (~x)
————
```

2: unpack single tar file

```
$ tar -x -v -f pack~1.tar
OR
$ tar -x -v -f pack~x.tar
```

3: unpack single tar file (with multiple parts, aka BIG tar)

```
$ tar -x -v -f pack~4.tar -F "pack.sh BIG"
```

4: unpack all tar file

```
$ ls -1 *.tar | xargs -I% tar -F "pack.sh BIG" -xf %
```