# Create TAR files with limited size in Unix script

Tags: scripting, tar

```
printf 'n Log-%02d.tar\n' {2..}|tar cf /var/opt/sw/e4/data/dev/e4_dev/DEVL3/EW/EWD1/DATA/AED/OUTPUT/Log-01.tar -ML1900m /var/opt/sw/e4/data/dev/e4_dev/DEVL3/EW/EWD1/DATA/AED/Temp
```

I tried to use the above code to tar 1000 files whose file size (varies)  greater than 2 GB, which needs to be archived as 1.9 GB separate TAR files.

For example, if there are 1500 files of size 7 GB, it needs to be archived as (7 GB/1.9 GB) 4 tar files:  `log-01.tar, ..., log-04.tar`
but I got the error:

```
printf: {2..} expected numeric value
tar: -ML1900m: No such file or directory
```

What should I change here? Is there a way to do this without using create volume method in GNU tar?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628102/how-to-create-split-tar-archive-in-multiple-stages-to-save-space/628125#comment1175418_628102

Comment: Why do you use `{2..}` instead of `{2..4}` as written in the [previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634990/332764)?

Comment: Because 4 was an example,according to the file size it may increase to 5 or 6 tar files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TAR 6 GB worth of files into separate 1.9 GB TAR files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634982/tar-6-gb-worth-of-files-into-separate-1-9-gb-tar-files)

Comment: *Exact* duplicate of [TAR 6 GB worth of files into separate 1.9 GB TAR files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/634982/97255), which has already been answered. Please don't post the same question twice. Update your previous question with new details, if need be.

Comment: `tar -M ` only asks for a new tape name when it needs it. So you might as well put in `{2..100}`: it won't read the ones it doesn't need, and the printf will go away when the pipe no longer has a reader.

Comment: You are aware that individual files can be split across output files 1-2, 2-3, and 3-4, so you may need to read two output files to extract a single original file?

Comment: i changed it to {2..10} and ML1900M but still get the error..what should i change ?

Comment: @Subramanian It seems you're using a shell that doesn't understand the sequence expression. Run the command in `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message basically says what the problem is, "1900m" is not recognised as an argument to '-L', and the man-page for `tar` explains it. You (quite sensibly as "m" is the prefix for "milli", which doesn't make sense with bytes) must use a capital "M" when you want to specify a number of megabytes (`tar`actually uses me*bi*bytes, but let's not get into that).